# Can you help me make more OOP abstraction with this code?

Tags: actionscript-3, oop

This code is not java code, and I'm not getting any answer from ActionScript developers. So I tagged it with java, but Action Script is similar to java and this an OOP question.

I'm using Grid Data and I want to accomplish this following task:

Method 1: I want to multiply  each row Row1num1 * Row1num2 and so on,

```
var Row1num1:String;
var Row2num2:String;

var Row2num1:String;
var Row2num2:String;

var Row3num1:String;
var Row3num2:String;

var event1:Object={num1:Row1num1,num2:Row1num2};
var event2:Object={num1:Row2num1,num2:Row2num2};
var event3:Object={num1:Row3num1,num2:Row3num2};

then add them to a dataGrid
dataGrid.columns =["num1","num2"];
dataGrid.addItem(event1);
dataGrid.addItem(event2);
dataGrid.addItem(event3);
```

but by using this method, if I have 20 rows, I will have a lot of variables, obviously it's bad.

method 2: In this method creating  Grid Data rows at runtime and multiply them.

```
//button to add rowGrid 
dd.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK,ddd);

var numm:String="34";
function ddd(evt:MouseEvent):void
{
    var event4:Object={num1:Rownum1,num2:Rownum2};
    dataGrid.addItem(event4);
}
```

but when I use this method, I have a hard time accessing each row data and multiply them.

This example because I'm creating GPA calculator and I want to take each row credit Hours and multiply them with the scale value at the same row, first method is bad because there's not abstraction .

The second method what I'm hoping to work ,because I want user to add row depend on their number of courses.

I hope my English is not bad.

I hope my question don't get vote down, and by reading this question can you determine what I'm missing so I can learn it .

And is there any tutorial I can use to solve my problem?

Comment: When you have multiple variable names than only differ by a number, it suggest that you probably need to use arrays. I believe arrays will solve a lot of your issues, especially having so much repeated code.

Comment: You may also want to create a "structure" which contains the credit hours and the weight. In Java, I would do this with a class. i don't know what you use in ActionScript.

Comment: I think you need to use arrays

Comment: ActionScript has not much to do with Java. Java != JavaScript.

Answer (score 0):

I'm just addressing your first method for now, but it almost seems at though you want an array of some sort.

[Here's a link on how to use Actionscript arrays.](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/Array.html)

If you need more dimensions, you can make an array of arrays.  This will help you cut down on the number of variables.

Answer (score 0):

I hope I correctly understood your question. I'll give it a go either way...

So, one of the best things about actionscript in comparison to most other strongly-typed Object-Oriented languages is how easy reflection is (probably thanks to its javascript origins). 
That being said, what you can do is simply create an array using a "for" loop. What I am assuming is that the variables row1Num1 row2Num2 and so on already exist in your class. Otherwise, obviously it would be much more efficient to store them in an array and simply read from it into a new array. Anyhow, the code should look something like this:

method 1:

```
var eventsArr:Array = [];
for(var i:int = 1; this["row" + i + "Num1"] != undefined /*or i<=length*/; i++){
    eventsArr.push({num1:this["row" + i + "Num1"], num2:this["row" + i + "Num2"]});
} 
for(var j:int = 0; j < eventsArr.length; j++){
    dataGrid.addItem(eventsArr[j]);
}
```

method 2:

```
dd.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK,ddd);

var numm:String="34"; //I am assuming this refers to the row number you wanted to add.
function ddd(evt:MouseEvent):void
{
    var event4:Object={num1:this["row" + numm + "Num1"],num2:this["row" + numm + "Num2"]};
    eventsArr.push(event4);
    dataGrid.addItem(event4);
}
```

Hope that helps.